# video tag is not support youtube videos. I want both youtube and azure media service link in my video app.I use <video> tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ionic-framework, youtube

video tag is not support youtube videos. I want both youtube and azure media service link in my video app.I use video  tag. I want to play both type of videos when src may a youtube or an ams link.

```
<video width="280" height="240" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" preload="none">
   <source src="{{Model.modulelink}}" autostart="false">     
</video>
```

`{{Model.modulelink}}` may be a youtubelink or an azure media service link. ams link play good but youtube link can't play. I know iframe tag will help. but i need to use both iframe and video tag. if youtube video link then use iframe else use video link. so kindly request you to give some way to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[Media Element.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube)

to achieve this.

**Include**:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" />
```

**then add:**

```
type="video/youtube"
```

to your source tag to play the YouTube Video

```
<video width="280" height="240" controls="controls" preload="none">
   <source type="video/youtube" src="{{Model.modulelink}}">     
</video>
```

Comment: It seems to be add jquery.js, mediaelement-and-player.min.js and mediaelementplayer.css. where from I got it??

Comment: can you suggest, where I can found that files@Ellery

Comment: here I got errors like Failed to load resource:mediaelement-and-player.min.js, mediaelementplayer.css, and jquery.js

Comment: Those files can be found at [Media Element.js](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/) and jQuery can be found at [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: I can't find any. If you have the files please give to me.or specify the root to get that files.

Comment: i got the files.no error. but still i can't watch the video